# VB.Net Saving CSV File

Tags: database, vb.net, csv

I'm stuck with this problem, I will use csv type as a my database rather than using access database or any kind of databases. The database system will be saving a csv file to the local hard drive rather than using databases. For example, If I will click the save button, textbox1.txt and textbox2.txt will be save to local hard drive with my sample.csv

Your help and suggestions will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Nino

Answer (score 0):

for reading / writing CSV I would recommend http://kbcsv.codeplex.com/